# c# null string?

Tags: c#, operator-precedence, null-coalescing-operator

I had the following:

```
string Name = name.First + " "  +  name.Last;
```

This returns `Tom Jones` just fine.

In case name.First may be null or name.Last may be null, I have the following:

```
string SpeakerName = name.First ?? string.Empty + " "  +  name.Last ?? string.Empty;
```

What is strange is that it only returns `Tom`. Why is this and how can I fix it such that `if null` it defaults to empty string for either first or last name?

Comment: search for "operator precedence".

Comment: To follow up on hazzik: `null` is converted to "" when used with the `+` operator where one of the operand expressions of `string`. e.g. `name.First + " " + name.Last` would yield the same output in this case. Similarly, `string.Format("{0} {1}", name.First, name.Last)` would work. However, generally, `"First "` or `" Last"` or `" "` is still not desired output, so that could be looked into ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of the relative precedence of the ?? and + operators.  Try this:

```
string SpeakerName = (name.First ?? "") + " " + (name.Last ?? "");
```

Your original example is evaluating as if it was:

```
string SpeakerName = name.First ?? ("" + " "  +  (name.Last ?? ""));
```

Also, read Jon's answer here: [What is the operator precedence of C# null-coalescing (??) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511093/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator?rq=1)

As he suggests there, this should work as well:

```
string SpeakerName = name.First + " " + name.Last;
```

Because that compiles to @L.B.'s answer below, minus the trim:

```
string SpeakerName = String.Format("{0} {1}", name.First, name.Last)
```

EDIT:

You also asked that first and last both == null makes the result an empty string.  Generally, this is solved by calling `.Trim()` on the result, but that isn't exactly equivalent.  For instance, you may for some reason *want* leading or trailing spaces if the names are not null, e.g. "  Fred" + "Astair " => "  Fred Astair ".  We all assumed that you would want to trim these out.  If you don't, then I'd suggest using a conditional:

```
string SpeakerName = name.First + " " + name.Last;
SpeakerName = SpeakerName == " " ? String.Empty : SpeakerName;
```

If you never want the leading or trailing spaces, just add a `.Trim()` as @L.B. did

Answer (score 6):

```
string SpeakerName = String.Format("{0} {1}", name.First, name.Last).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string SpeakerName = name.First != null && name.Last != null 
                     ? string.Format("{0} {1}", name.First, name.Last) 
                     : string.Empty;
```

Comment: +1 for reading and understanding ..."such that if null it defaults to empty string for either first or last name" ...the same way I do

Answer (score -1):

```
string fullName = (name.First + " "  +  name.Last).Trim();
```

This works for either or both being null and will not return a string with leading, trailing, or only spaces.