# Why do i need to put the null-coalescing operator in brackets?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, nullable

I have recently noticed a curiosity (at least for me). I thought that the [`null-coalescing operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) would take the precedence over any mathematical operation but obviously i was wrong. I thought following two variables would have the same value at the end:

```
double? previousValue = null;
double? v1 = 1 + previousValue ?? 0;
double? v2 = 1 + (previousValue ?? 0);
```

But `v2.Value` is (the desired) 1 whereas `v1.Value` is still 0. Why?

[Demo](http://ideone.com/gRZoe9)

Comment: might help: http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_14.2.1_Operator_precedence_and_associativity also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511093/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`v1` is 0 for the exact reason you mentioned: the null-coalescing operator actually has relatively low precedence. [This table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) shows exactly how low.

So for the first expression, `1 + null` is evaluated first, and it evaluates to a `null int?`, which then coalesces to 0.

Answer (score 1):

v2 is saying,1 plus (if previousValue == null add to 1 the value 0,which gives 1.The 
v1 is saying 1 plus null is null so lets give back the 0.