# Null Coalesce returning value of first non null variable

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I'm trying to add several integers together using `NULL Coalesce`, in which at least 2 of the integers *may* be NULL, in that case, assign 0 to such integers and then add.

```
var total = votes[0].Value ?? 0 + votes[1].Value ?? 0 + votes[2].Value ?? 0 + votes[3].Value ?? 0;
```

`total` returns the value of `votes[0].Value` instead of addition of all four variables.

Is there a way I can get the total of all the integers?

Comment: Are you sure the array has the values you think it does?  If you break on it, and inspect their values...

Comment: Yes it does when I step through in debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the operator precedence of C# null-coalescing (??) operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511093/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 4):

```
var total = votes.Sum();
```

It will count null values as zero.

Comment: "null values as zero": while this is effectively true for `Sum`, it is more general to say it skips null values. That way, it applies to `Average` and others, too. (But, not `Count` of course.)

Answer (score 1):

That code is equivalent to:

```
var total = votes[0].Value ?? (0 + votes[1].Value ?? (0 + votes[2].Value ?? (0 + votes[3].Value ?? 0)));
```

So it should be rather apparent now why it returns `votes[0].Value` rather than the sum of all of the non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

If *votes* is an array of nullable integers you can write:

```
var votes = new int?[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var total = (votes[0] ?? 0) + (votes[1] ?? 0) + (votes[2] ?? 0) + (votes[3] ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is cleaner and it will skip the null values:

```
var total = votes.Sum();
```

Comment: thanks. I thought that would not work for nulls but it does.