# Concatenate nullable object with string

Tags: c#

This:

```
int? temp = 0;
return "123 " + temp ?? "null" + " 456";
```

returns `123 0`, but I expected: `123 0 456`

This:

```
int? temp = null;
return "123 " + temp ?? "null" + " 456";
```

returns `123` , but I expected: `123 null 456`

How can I get expected results?

Comment: `return "123 " + (temp ?? "null") + " 456";`, please note `(...)`. Your current code does `return "123 " + temp ?? ("null" + " 456");`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that doesnt compile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the operator precedence of C# null-coalescing (??) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511093/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the precedence of the `??` operator. Use

```
return "123 " + (temp?.ToString() ?? "null") + " 456";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does

```
  int? temp = 0;
  return "123 " + temp ?? ("null" + " 456");
```

Put it in different order:

```
  int? temp = 0;
  return "123 " + (temp?.ToString() ?? "null") + " 456";
```

Or, in order to get rid of pesky `+`:

```
  return $"123 {temp?.ToString() ?? "null"} 456";
```

Answer (score 0):

So many fancy solutions here already, I'll add a simple "old stylish one" :)

```
"123 " + (temp.HasValue ? temp.ToString() : "null") + " 456"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of writing it that should work:

```
$"123 {(temp == null ? "null" : temp.ToString())} 456"
```