# C# null-conditional/null-coalescing operator precompiler bug or am I just missing something?

Tags: c#, compilation, operator-precedence, null-coalescing-operator, or-operator

I just pushed some bad code that caused an issue in release and wanted to see if anyone could help clarify what's going on here.

Below is a (contrived but runnable) program that illustrates the issue I'm having. The line in question is the `if` statement in the `foreach` loop of the `Main` method.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string[] arr = new[] { "a","b","c"};
        string s = "y3";
        X x = new X();
        
        foreach(string a in arr)
        {
            if(x.Y?.Contains(a) ?? false || s == x.S)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class X
{
    public string S = "y3";
    public List<string> Y = new(){ "y1", "y2" };
}
```

In this code, we have an expression that uses a null-conditional operator alongside a null-coalescing operator to check whether the list `Y` in `x` (which could be null) contains `a` or another external condition is met. If either condition is met, it should execute the block--in this case, print to the console.

Running this code produces no print statements, which is counterintuitive to me. However, if I add parenthesis to the offending expression, for example, `if((x.Y?.Contains(a) ?? false) || s == x.S)`, everything works as intended and items get printed to the console.

So I put this code into SharpLab (against the main (24 Jan 2023) baseline) to see what was going on and found some interesting results.

When the initial code is pre-compiled in its original form, the pre-compiler generates a ternary  expression, effectively short-circuiting the `||` operator whenever `Y` is not null:

```
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array = new string[3];
        array[0] = "a";
        array[1] = "b";
        array[2] = "c";
        string text = "y3";
        X x = new X();
        string[] array2 = array;
        int num = 0;
        while (num < array2.Length)
        {
            string text2 = array2[num];
            List<string> y = x.Y;
            if ((y != null) ? y.Contains(text2) : (text == x.S))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text2);
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
```

When parentheses are added, the pre-compiler generates the following:

```
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array = new string[3];
        array[0] = "a";
        array[1] = "b";
        array[2] = "c";
        string text = "y3";
        X x = new X();
        string[] array2 = array;
        int num = 0;
        while (num < array2.Length)
        {
            string text2 = array2[num];
            List<string> y = x.Y;
            if ((y != null && y.Contains(text2)) || text == x.S)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text2);
            }
            num++;
        }
    }
```

In this version, the original intent is captured and the lines are printed as expected.

I read some things saying that the null-coalescing operator is right-associative and thought maybe it has something to do with that, but I'm not sure because I would assume that the logic would still work in that case.

I also thought that it could be different across compiler versions but haven't tried to track that down yet.

Just looking for opinions to see if there is something I don't understand or that I'm missing here or if it is just a gotcha I need to look out for in the future.

Comment: This looks like precedence at work to me... `||` "binds tighter" than `??`, so your original condition is equivalent to `x.Y?.Contains(a) ?? (false || s == x.S)`. Does that explain it for you? (I suspect so, but I haven't spent long looking closely.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511093/what-is-the-operator-precedence-of-c-sharp-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: @JonSkeet -- that makes perfect sense. When viewed this way, I can more easily see why the condition was being thrown out altogether if the list wasn't null.

Comment: I'm always getting code review comments that some of my parentheses are not needed.  My policy is to always indicate my operator binding intent if there's any chance of ambiguity, both to let the compiler know what I'm thinking and to make things explicit for the maintenance programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [the C# operator precedence table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), you will see why this is happening

| Operators | Category or name |
| --- | --- |
| ... |  |
| `x && y` | Conditional AND |
| `x || y` | Conditional OR |
| `x ?? y` | Null-coalescing operator |
| `c ? t : f` | Conditional operator |

What this means is that `||` has a higher precedence than `??`, so `false` is being bound to `s == x.S`. Effectively, you have this:

```
x.Y?.Contains(a) ?? (false || s == x.S)
```

Which is not your intention. This is why you should not rely on operator precedence except in the most obvious cases.

Aside, there is another syntax that works better

```
x.Y?.Contains(a) == true || s == x.S
```

In this case, it's fairly obvious to most that `==` has a higher precedence than `||`, so I think the `()` could be forgone.